# My java calculator is returning the error "one can not be resolved to a variable"?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java calculator that works for multiplication, division, subtraction and addition. I am just starting the division part and it is incomplete, however I am getting an error that says "one can not be resolved to a variable". At this certain spot I want to make it so if they type in "one" it will start the division class. Code for main class:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("This is a calculator that can divide, multiply, subtract and add. To divide type in one, to multiply type in two, to subtract type in three and to add type in four");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int div, mult, sub, add;

        if (input = one) {
            division divisionObject = new division();
        }

        div = input.nextInt();

        mult = input.nextInt();

        sub = input.nextInt();

        add = input.nextInt();

        if(div > mult && div > sub && div >add){

        }

    }
}
```

Code for division class(I have not touched the other classes yet):
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class division {
    public static void divide() {
        int div1, div2, divanswer;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to divide: ");
        div1 = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

P.S Keep in mind I have only been coding in java for like half a week so I am a complete noob.

Comment: How does input = one?

Comment: I meant if they typed in one, then execute this code.

Comment: So, the first thing to do is search for examples on using Scanner. That's been asked already for sure.

Comment: Where is `one` defined?  Also `=` is used for assignment, `==` for comparison or equality.  I "think" you mean `if ("one".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {...`

Comment: read up about the Scanenr class and how to use it.  Also remember to use `String.equals` when comparing Strings

Comment: I defined one just now as a string and changed the equals and now it says string can not be resolved to a type

Comment: @CosmicBatz: Sounds like you've declared it as `string` rather than `String`.

Comment: Yup i did and fixed it now on the if statement it says one cannot be resolved to a variable and Incompatible operand types Scanner and String

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **String variable** to store the choice entered by user like "one".

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String choice = input.nextLine();
```

Also, change your if condition to :

```
if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("one"))
```

`{ 
   division divisionObject = new division(); 
 }`

this will check the **choice** entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

what is one ?? is it defined anywhere? because if it is a string it has to be quoted like `"one"` or if it is a variable in which you have stored string then  you'll have to use this code:

```
     String stringVal=input.nextLine();// use this for string as an input
    //or   
     int intValue=input.nextLine();// use this for integer as an input  
//use any of the below statement based on their declaration.(intValue==1) or (stringVal.equalsIgnoreCase("one"))
        if ((intValue==1)||(stringVal.equalsIgnoreCase("one")))
 {
                    division divisionObject = new division();
                }
```

instead of using this :

```
    if (input = one) {
                division divisionObject = new division();
            }
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rectify with this , u will get ur mistake:=

```
import java.util.*;

public class Algebra {
 public static void main(String []args){
  int n=0;
  float result;


  System.out.println("1.Addition");
  System.out.println("2.Subtarction");
  System.out.println("3.Multiplication");
  System.out.println("4.Division");

  float a = 0,b = 0;
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a and b");
  a=sc.nextInt();
  b=sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter ur choice");
  n=sc.nextInt();

  switch (n)
  {
   case 1: result=a+b;
           System.out.println("Sum is "+result);
           break;
   case 2: result=a-b;
           System.out.println("Sub is "+result);
           break;
   case 3: result=a*b;
           System.out.println("mult is "+result);
           break;
   case 4: result=a/b;
           System.out.println("div is "+result);
           break;    
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You never declared one as a variable...

If you want to use it try adding in.

```
     int one;
```

somewhere. I'm not saying anything else is right. but this is why you are getting an error.

read more on your issue. you need to store the user input as one in order to compare. you have a reference to nowhere.

Comment: It's clear that declaring one as anything will not fix the problem that scanner can't be assigned nor equated directly to `one` unless itself is a scanner.

Comment: scanners need to be used to scan through all text entered. if it's one variable you can use scannerDeclaration.nextInt();

Comment: Check the documentation for examples. 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I'm aware of that. Your edit covers the point I was getting at. You're right, it does help with the error although they were wanting to check against a "one" string.

Comment: if (input = one) {
            division divisionObject = new division();
        }

did you mean input == one? 

Also what are you trying to accomplish with that comparison?

Comment: just realized you aren't the poster. sorry.

Comment: I believe the poster was trying to simply put 

input == 1